# JSP not displaying DB data on index page, Java Web App using Derby

Tags: java, html, jsp, for-loop, derby

I am building a simple CRUD application and after the form is submitted, the data goes to the DB. I am trying to loop through the data and show it in a listing page but cannot make it work and after hours of searching,, I come to you for an answer.

This the the listing page code where data is to be displayed. The DAO and Bean class all seem to be in order but I'll gladly upload if needed. Thanks.

```
<%@ page import="java.util.List, models.beans.*, models.entity.*"%>
<jsp:useBean id="load" class="models.beans.LoadBean" scope="request"></jsp:useBean>

<% List<Load> loadListing = load.findAll();%>

<% for (Load lod : loadListing) {%>

  <div class ="row container-fluid">
    <div class="list-group col-md-6 inline">
      <a href="#load" class="list-group-item " data-toggle="collapse"><b><%= lod.getApptTime()%><span class="space"></span><%= lod.getCarrier()%></b></a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="load" class="collapse">
<div id="dvData">
<table class="table">
    <tr class="row">
      <th class="col-md-1 main-h">Order #</th>
      <th class="col-md-1 main-h">Vendor</th>
      <th class="col-md-1 main-h">Cases</th>
      <th class="col-md-1 main-h">Pallets</th>
      <th class="col-md-2 text-center main-h">Unload Start</th>
      <th class="col-md-2 text-center main-h">Unload End</th>
      <th class="col-md-2 main-h">Total Cost</th>
      <th class="col-md-2 main-h">Notify Driver</th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="row">
      <td class="col-md-1"><%= lod.getWorkOrder()%></td>
      <td class="col-md-1"><%= lod.getVendor()%></td>
      <td class="col-md-1"><%= lod.getCases()%></td>    
      <td class="col-md-1"><%= lod.getPallets()%></td>
      <td>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type='text' class="form-control" value="<%= lod.getUnldStart()%>" readonly/>
        </div>
      </td>

      <td>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type='text' class="form-control" value="<%= lod.getUnldEnd()%>" readonly/>
        </div>
      </td>

      <td>    
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type='text' class="form-control" value="$234.34" readonly/>
        </div> 
      </td>

      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary">Send</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" href="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/pages/form.jsp?id=<%= lod.getId()%>">Edit
      </td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" href="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/pages/delete.jsp?id=<%= lod.getId()%>">Delete
      </td>
    </tr>
    <%}%>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not a good way. Do tutorial http://o7planning.org/en/10285/create-a-simple-java-web-application-using-servlet-jsp-and-jdbc#a827434

Answer (score 0):

```
Try out this i think this will help you-
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:forEach items="${yourList}" var="var">
       <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${count = count+1 }" /></td>
        <td>${var.attributeName}</td>
       </tr>
      </c:forEach>
```